# Import data from large file to list

Tags: python, list, file

I'm working on large dataset analysis. I run into problems due to processing time (15 days!).
Most time is spent on importing data from a text file. I think that this part can be optimized, but I don't know how.
Currently I'm importing with:

```
def lines(filename):
    f = open(filename)                  
    lines = 0
    buf_size = 1024 * 1024
    read_f = f.read # loop optimization

    buf = read_f(buf_size)
    while buf:
        lines += buf.count('\n')
        buf = read_f(buf_size)

def importdata(x, y, filename2):
    ts = time.time()    
    nfiles = lines(filename2)+1  
    counter = 0
    search = '[' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y) + ']'
    output_list = []
    print "test" ,time.time()-ts
    ts = time.time()
    with open(filename2) as fobj:
        for counter, line in enumerate(fobj, 1):
            if search in line:
                coordinate = json.loads(next(fobj))
        output_list.extend(coordinate)
        if counter == nfiles :
            output = "Bad pixel"
        else:
            output = output_list
print "time", time.time()-ts
return output
```

I have the following file format:

```
[12,512]
[51, 64, 85,12, 23]
[13, 45]
[83, 27, 28, 19, 3]
[17, 35]
[54, 78, 38, 19, 2]
[12, 512]
[23, 65, 6, 5, 45]
```

e.g running importdata(12, 512, filename2) should return

[51, 64, 85,12, 23, 23, 65, 6, 5, 45]

If x, y are not in the file output should return "Bad pixel".

Files are approx 1g and I read the output as follows

x,y, file 1
x,y, file 2
x,y, file 3
x2, y2, file 1
x2, y2, file 2

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not really clear what your function `importdata` is supposed to do. What are `x` and `y`? Also, the second line of `importdata` can't work, because the function `lines` always returns `None`.

Comment: Hi @wesley, what about using concurrent data load, show instead of trying load all the file at the same time, use different machines to do that?
The problem could be the overload of memory so, I advice you to use HDFS.

Comment: @SvenFestersen, importdata doesn't return None. In another function I put in an existing filename2.

Comment: Your function `lines` always returns `None`, because you are not explicitly returning anything. The second line of `importdata` must thus fail (you are adding `1` to `None`). Or something is missing in the code in your question.